# How to select a value from a column which is based on other row and column value?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Well, best explained with a example:

```
MYSQL TABLE NAME: CLIENTS
ID        NAME        CODE
1         Mark        0
2         Joe         1
```

What I want:

```
HTML TABLE:
MATCH        NAME
Mark         Joe
```

Did you get it? Like, I need to take the NAME from the person who has a ID equal to the CODE of other.

I think that you won't need my code, since I just want to know the function that allows me to echo two distinct "NAMES". Like, if I call two `echo $name;` how the code knows who is who?

Ps.: I'm not a back-end developer, take it easy =)
Ps².: It is a loop (what I know to do hehehehe), it has to repeat that "search" and list a lot of "MATCHES", you know?

Comment: [SQL self joins](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm) might help you... something like `SELECT a.name, b.name
FROM CLIENTS a, CLIENTS b
WHERE a.id = b.code;`

Comment: Yes, that solved. The same as Kunal's answer =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can find reord in the same table by using self join...

```
SELECT e.NAME as parent, m.NAME as child FROM CLIENTS e, CLIENTS m WHERE e.ID = m.CODE
```

Hope this will be your solution

Comment: That solutioned my problem. I just add some wheres and everything is fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Using Mysql `JOIN`

```
SELECT b.name, a.name as match_name
FROM clients a
JOIN clients b
ON a.id = b.code;
```

> Output

```
+------+------------+
| name | match_name |
+------+------------+
| Joe |     Mark    |
+------+------------+
```

Comment: I don't have to select CODE or ID before use them?

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say, I already have a WHERE. Everyone who needs to be listed has a "TYPE" column equal to 2. Like, Joe is TYPE = 2, but Mark isn't.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but Kunal's answerd solved my problem =)

Comment: Cool. Kunal's query is also correct. I used `JOINS` and he has used native way of joining tables. Both the queries will output the same result.